# How to select a value, which is optional - using jq

Tags: json, jq

This is how I am trying to ouput the message of an array element using `jq`

```
echo '{ errors: [{ "code": "INVALID", "message": "message" }] }' | jq -r '.errors[0].message'
```

But `errors` is an optional value. If there is no error, the field is missing. How do I have to handle the optional value correctly in `jq`?

So in the example the result is `message` and if there is no error, the result is empty.

Comment: Your current attempt produces `null`. If you want some other result, please say what that should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an `if … then … else … end` expression (see the [manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#if-then-else)) checking the existence of a field using `has` (see the [manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#has%28key%29)):

```bash
… | jq -r 'if has("errors") then .errors[0].message else "no errors" end'
```

Alternatively, use the alternative operator `//` which is triggered on `null` or `false` (see the [manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Alternativeoperator%3A%2F%2F)):

```bash
… | jq -r '.errors[0].message // "no errors"'
```

If your code would run into an exception, you can also equip the test with the error suppression operator `?` (see the [manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#ErrorSuppression%2FOptionalOperator%3A%3F)), which is not necessary with your sample code as it evaluates to `null` without errors if the `.errors` field was missing (see the [manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#ObjectIdentifier-Index%3A.foo%2C.foo.bar): "it produces the value at the key, or `null` if there's none present."):

```bash
… | jq -r '(.errors[0].message)? // "no errors"'
```

As @SUTerliakov pointed out, you can use `empty` anywhere in these examples instead of (the dummy string) `"no errors"` if you want no result at all on success.

Comment: `(.errors[0].message)? // empty` can be used if you don't want any output at all.